# Concat return values from different methods in same class to one value in another method

Tags: c#, function, methods

is it possible to concat different return values from different methods in the same class to one method? What I am trying to do is I want to take all the return values from all the methods/functions and I am trying to bring them together as one string or number in my public static int GenerateId().

Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int dateofbirth;
        string name;
        string surname;
        string firstletr;


        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your Date of Birth in next sequence: yymmdd");
        int dob = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        dateofbirth = Idenity.DateOfBirth(dob);
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your firsletter of your name :");
        name = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your firsletter of your surname:");
        surname = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

        firstletr = Idenity.FirstLetters(name, surname);
        Console.Clear();


    }

}
class Idenity
{
    int dateofbirth, x, y, z;
    string name, surname, male, female;

    public static int DateOfBirth(int dateofbirth)
    {
        int FirstSixDigits = dateofbirth;

        return FirstSixDigits; //6
    }
    public static string FirstLetters(string name, string surname)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> firstletters = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        firstletters.Add("A", 1);
        firstletters.Add("B", 2);
        firstletters.Add("C", 3); 
        firstletters.Add("D", 4);
        firstletters.Add("E", 5);
        firstletters.Add("F", 6);
        firstletters.Add("G", 7);
        firstletters.Add("H", 8);
        firstletters.Add("I", 9);
        firstletters.Add("J", 10);
        firstletters.Add("K", 11);
        firstletters.Add("L", 12);
        firstletters.Add("M", 13);
        firstletters.Add("N", 14);
        firstletters.Add("O", 15);
        firstletters.Add("P", 16);
        firstletters.Add("Q", 17);
        firstletters.Add("R", 18);
        firstletters.Add("S", 19);
        firstletters.Add("T", 20);
        firstletters.Add("U", 21);
        firstletters.Add("V", 22);
        firstletters.Add("W", 23);
        firstletters.Add("X", 24);
        firstletters.Add("Y", 25);
        firstletters.Add("Z", 26);

        int valueFirstletters = int.Parse(firstletters[name].ToString() + firstletters[surname].ToString());


        return valueFirstletters.ToString();//3

    }
    public static string Gender(string male, string female)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> gender = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            gender.Add("M", 1);
            gender.Add("F", 2);
            int valueGender = 0;

            if (male == "M")
            {
                valueGender = gender[male];
                return valueGender.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                valueGender = gender[female];
                return valueGender.ToString();
            }//1


        }

    public static int Randomize(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        Random first = new Random();
        x = first.Next(0,9);
        Random second = new Random();
        y = second.Next(0, 9);
        Random third = new Random();
        z = third.Next(0, 9);

        int valueRandomize = int.Parse(x.ToString() + y.ToString() + z.ToString());

        return valueRandomize;//3

    }
    public static int GenerateId()
    {
        int IDNumber = 0;
        IDNumber = DateOfBirth(dateofbirth);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I'm thinking: Serialization...

Comment: Yes, of course you can concatenate various return values as a string/number, depending on the return types or what exactly you're trying to return in the end. Can you explain your code a little more and what youre trying to concatenate? What's the issue you're having? What inputs are giving you what outputs? What are you expecting/wanting?

Comment: Im trying to generate an ID number from all the inputs of the user using methods :)

Comment: Just a tip: try to use only one instance of the `Random` class to prevent generating the same numbers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Comment: There's so much that doesnt even make sense. `DateofBirth` method just returns exactly what parameter you gave it. Huh? Your `FirstLetters` name wont do what you think it does... i think `firstletters[name]` should be `firstletters[name.Substring(0,1)]` if you're going to get a match on a first initial at all. `Gender` method makes no sense... `Randomize` just totally throws away all 3 parameters... I dont get how you're trying to generate this ID or what result you're trying to get

Comment: I tested it tnw, it works one hundred percent, I am trying to concat the return values. Do not stress about the rest of  the code. It does what I want it to do.

Comment: Also for REAL number generation use this guy. Random is only pseudo random, but probably fine for you classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Comment: LULZ tnw -- yeah it's pretty terrible and mostly makes absolutely no sense but if you look at her profile you will notice she is a student and this is her beginning to learn to code.  So I would cut some slack. ;)

On another note. Marietjie Davel feel free to email me for some help if you want it.

Comment: @MarietjieDavel If you just want to concat the return values, HOW do you want to concat them? You never answered that question.